# What is bridge_fd?

Tags: ubuntu, bridge, kvm-virtualization

I'm creating bridge network on Ubuntu 9.04(server)

I set up following configuration file

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
network 192.168.1.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_fd 9
bridge_hello 2
bridge_maxage 12
bridge_stp off
```

I don't know this parameter meenings
bridge_fd,bridge_hello,bridge_maxage,bridge_stp

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the forwarding delay for interfaces joining the bridge. It's how long it'll be before the interface will be able to do anything. . During this time the bridge will be discovering other bridges and checking that no loops are created. For a better description and the reason for it you need to read up on spanning tree protocol.

Comment: "how long it'll be" in seconds

Answer (score 5):

They correspond to brctl settings.  Look at [man brctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/brctl.8.html).

> brctl(8) can be used for configuring  certain  spanning  tree  protocol parameters. For an explanation of these parameters, see the IEEE 802.1d specification. The default values should be  just fine.  If you don’t know what these parameters mean, you probably won’t feel the desire to tweak them.

Comment: A slightly better resource is the [bridge-utils-interfaces manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/bridge-utils-interfaces.5.html).